# How much battery power for LED and how to make it flicker

Tags: led, batteries, battery-operated, dimmer, dimming

I am trying to figure out what configuration of battery(ies) I need to power [this LED](https://www.ledsupply.com/leds/cree-xlamp-xpg2-high-power-led). I am only using one (specifically the warm white 1-up).

I am also looking to make it flicker like a candle with the smallest item possible that will NOT reset every time it is turned on/off. I need to to always turn on and flicker correctly. **EDIT/ADD: Is there a resister I can include in a simple circuit with a battery pack to make it flicker? It seems like thats what a lot of the cheap tea lights use.**

For context I am trying to make super bright LED candles. So everything I use needs to be able to fit into a smallish pillar candle (~1.5-2.5" diameter x min 6" height). And I am on a pretty tight budget, so please let me know what are the cheapest options.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not reset when every time it is turned off". Reset what? The thing you describe has no memory to forget anything when turned off.

Comment: I have used string lights and other things before that have multiple modes and it resets back to the beginning of the mode options every time it is turned on.

Comment: Those are simple, stupid LEDs.  No worries about resetting a controller.  Just about supplying the current.  Maximum brightnes (1.5 ampere) is a lot for a battery if you want it to last for a while.

Comment: Lasting even 1-2 hours would be great.

Answer (score 2):

That's a high quality LED (if genuine) - depending on volume then an Asian sourced semi-equivalent would be much cheaper.

Battery life is very very dependant on operating current.
For a battery of adequate voltage across the operating time

- Operating life =  Battery_mAh_capacity / LED-mA.

If you operate the LED at 700 mA then

- 3 x AA Alkaline cells with a capacity of ABOUT 3000 mAh would ooerate the LED for about
  time = battery_mAh/LED_mAh = 3000/700 = 4+ hours.
- A rechargeable 18650 LiIon cell of 3000 mAh would provide similar operating time.

If "cheating" is acceptable, using an existing (low cost) low power flickering-candle-LED to drive your power LED, similar to [this circuit](http://www.discovercircuits.com/H-Corner/HC-Flameless%20LED%20Candle%20Power%20Boost.htm) by the great Dave Johnson, or a simple but elegantish version [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Flickering-LED-Candle-Mod/).

Alternatives could be a low cost microcontroller (from about 20 cents US)  - [ATtiny85 example here](https://www.barrywise.com/2016/11/attiny85-circuit-simulated-flickering-candle-flame/) and [ATtiny13 version here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Flickering-LED-Candle/) or a counter IC connected to form a pseudo-random number generator.

Many ideas here - [Google image search on - candle flicker circuit](https://www.google.com/search?q=candle+flicker+circuit&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWk9nrw63iAhVJRo8KHfcKD9oQsAR6BAglEAE&biw=1152&bih=606)

Comment: So I could I use 4 x AA alkaline batteries (just to get a battery holder that will fit in my candle)?

Comment: @Nova You will need a means of regulating the supply to suit the LED and any circuitry. 3 x AA = about 3.3V - 4.5V flat to new. 4 x AA = 4.4V - 6V . You will get NO MORE lifetime with a linear regulator from 4 cells than you get from 3. With a switchmode regulator you get SLIGHTLY more. You still need to decide on a Flicker-circuit. You can use a 4 x AA holder with 3 x AA by soldering a wire across one of the positions - be SURE that  a cell never gets inserted in that position.